# Sql returns row multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following sql:

```
select `items`.`id`, `items`.`item_url`, `items`.`title`, `items`.`description`, `items`.`item_image_name`, `items`.`downloads`, `items`.`likes`, `items`.`date` 
from `items` left join `categories` as `c` on `c`.`id` = `items`.`category_id` 
 left join `item_tags` as `it` on `it`.`item_id` = `items`.`id` 
 inner join `tags` as `t` on `t`.`id` = `it`.`tag_id` 
 where (`items`.`title` LIKE '%psd%' or `c`.`name` LIKE '%psd%' or `t`.`name` LIKE '%psd%') 
 order by `items`.`date` desc limit 12
```

But for some reason some rows repeats multiple times from items table. Is there a way to take results from items without repeating the same item id.

Comment: This question needs to be formatted better. Edit: yay

Comment: Either use DISTINCT or use a while loop (or other loop) to filter out the repeats

Comment: Without seeing the table or a portion of it it would be hard to know why duplicate results are returned. Can you share that with us? Or perhaps setup a sqlfiddle?

Comment: I would NOT advocate using a distinct if you don't know what the cause is for record duplication. It may indicate something else wrong in the database or query. First figure out where the 'repeating' records come from, then look for a solution. Show us table structure, sample data etc for an answer.

Comment: I assume that you're using MySql, then remove the Sql-Server tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use **DISTINCT** if you want to avoid duplicate data. Something like this:

```
select DISTINCT `items`.`id`, `items`.`item_url`, `items`.`title`, `items`.`description`, `items`.`item_image_name`, `items`.`downloads`, `items`.`likes`, `items`.`date` 
from `items` left join `categories` as `c` on `c`.`id` = `items`.`category_id` 
 left join `item_tags` as `it` on `it`.`item_id` = `items`.`id` 
 inner join `tags` as `t` on `t`.`id` = `it`.`tag_id` 
 where (`items`.`title` LIKE '%psd%' or `c`.`name` LIKE '%psd%' or `t`.`name` LIKE '%psd%') 
 order by `items`.`date` desc limit 12
```

or you can use **GROUP BY** also

```
select `items`.`id`, `items`.`item_url`, `items`.`title`, `items`.`description`, `items`.`item_image_name`, `items`.`downloads`, `items`.`likes`, `items`.`date` 
    from `items` left join `categories` as `c` on `c`.`id` = `items`.`category_id` 
     left join `item_tags` as `it` on `it`.`item_id` = `items`.`id` 
     inner join `tags` as `t` on `t`.`id` = `it`.`tag_id` 
     where (`items`.`title` LIKE '%psd%' or `c`.`name` LIKE '%psd%' or `t`.`name` LIKE '%psd%') 
     group by `items`.`id`, `items`.`item_url`, `items`.`title`, `items`.`description`, `items`.`item_image_name`, `items`.`downloads`, `items`.`likes`, `items`.`date` 
     order by `items`.`date` desc limit 12
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, distinct method did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DISTINCT keyword in your query:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

Comment: This is a comment, no?

Answer (score 0):

You need a "GROUP BY items.id"